# The sum of the present ages of a mother and her son is $42$. What was the mother's age $15$ years ago before her son was born?

Tags: linear-algebra

> The sum of the present ages of a mother and her son is $42$. When the mother was same age as her son now, her son wouldn't be born until $15$ years later. What was the mother's age when her son was born?

This question had seemed a bit complex. However, we can say that

$$M + S = 42 \tag {1}$$

where $M = \text{Mother}$, $S = \text{Son}$

> Mother's age $15$ years ago before her son was born

$$ M-t = -S-15 \tag{2}$$

$$t = \text{passed time}$$

This is where I'm stuck. I'll be waiting for your professional helps.

Comment: I think the question is a bit unclear. The only way it makes sense is if the son is actually fifteen.

Comment: @Johanna That was what I thought. However, if you got the problem correctly, you see. What was the mother's age 15 years ago before her son was born? -  15 years ago before her son was born, $-S - 15$ Plug any value to check it out, let's say $S = 15$, $-S = -15$ we get $0$ and then if 15 years passed, $-15$ finally we get $-S-15$. Sorry If I'm wrong.

Comment: Oh, I'm rewriting the question.

Comment: See the new edit, that's more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $M+S=42$, assume that the mother is $t$ years older than her son.

Currently, the mother is $M$ years old and the son is $S$ years old.

$\Rightarrow$ $t$ years ago, the mother was $M-t=S$ years old and her son was $S-t$ years old. Note that the son wouldn't be given birth until $15$ years later, so at this point we consider that her son was $-15$ years old or $S-t=-15$.

We have this set of equations:

$${\begin{cases}M+S=42\\M-S-t=0\\S-t=-15\end{cases}}$$

After solving this, you can check the answer below.

> The mother is currently $33$ years old, the son is currently $9$ years old.

Comment: I realize that I have written the set of equations wrong (it was $S-t=15$ before I edited it, which is wrong). Also edit to add the solution as a spoiler alert.

Comment: What a great answer you gave!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have enough information to solve the problem.  Your $M+S=42$ is correct, but you need another equation to sort them out.  Please check the problem.

Added after the edit:  When the mother was as old as the son is now is $M-S$ years ago.  In the second sentence we are told $S-(M-S)=2S-M=-15$, where the $-15$ represents $15$ years until the son is born.  We now have two equations in two unknowns.
$$M+S=42\\2S-M=-15$$ adding
$$3S=27\\S=9\\M=33$$
The age of the mother at the son's birth is the difference in ages, which is $24$.

Comment: That should be correct. Are you sure you got the problem carefully?

Comment: See the new edit, it would be more clear.

Comment: I didn't get your answer, could you make the equations with the variable $t$?

Comment: $t=M-S$.  The mother is now $33$ and we are talking about when she was $9$.  The third equation would then be $S-t=-15$.  Those two replace my second equation and give you three equations in the three unknowns $S,M,t$

Answer (score 0):

Let define the following uknowns

- $M$ mother's present age
- $S$ son's present age

then we have

- $M + S = 42\implies S=42-M$

from the condition "when the mother was same age as her son, there was 15 years her son to be born" corresponds to

- mother's age when son born: $S+15=M-S \implies M=2S+15$

then

- $M=84-2M+15 \implies 3M=99 \implies M=33$

Comment: See the new edit, that's more clear.

Comment: Could you use the variable $t$?

Comment: @Hamilton this equation $M-t = -S-15 $ is meaningless since M should be negative, a better way is to write the mother's age when the son is born that is $M-S$ (by definition of M and S) and it is $S+15$ from the second information thus $S+15=M-S$.

Comment: @Hamilton You don't need more variables than M and S to solve the problem, since we have only two conditions (i.e. equations) we need to use only 2 variables that are M and S.

Comment: @Hamilton Or better, we can also add another variable but it is not necessary. What does "t" mean in your idea? It is the passed time by?